# How to concatenate row value with column name

Tags: python

My input table

| index | income | Education | age1to_20 | age21to_30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Required output table

| index | income | Education | age1to_20 | age21to_30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | income_1 | Education_0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | income_2 | Education_2 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | income_1 | Education_0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | income_3 | Education_1 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | income_1 | Education_3 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | income_2 | Education_0 | 0 | 1 |

Tried below method but getting "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'income_1' error". Writing if clause is not sufficient when I have large number of columns that I need to update. I need to concatenate column name with row value

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row['income']==1:
    df.at[index,'income'] = 'income_1'
  else:
    df.at[index,'income'] = 'income_2'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your approach is that you're trying to change the entries of an `int` column to a string. One solution is to simply add `df['income'] = df['income'].astype(str)` before your loop. For example, you should find that

```
df['income'] = df['income'].astype(str)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[index,'income'] = 'income_' + df.at[index,'income']
```

leads to the desired change to the income column. More simply, however, you could just do the following:

```
df['income'] = 'income_' + df['income'].astype(str)
```

For your multiple columns, you could do something like this:

```
for col in ['income','Education']:
    df[col] = col + '_' + df[col].astype(str)
```

Alternatively (and I suspect that this is faster):

```
idx = list(map(df.columns.get_loc,["income","Education"]))
df.iloc[:,idx] = df.columns[idx] + '_' + df.iloc[:,idx].astype(str)
```

Comment: what if I want to update multiple column row values? Do I have df.at statement for each column name? For example I want to update both education and income columns

Comment: @nuke See my latest edit